# Windows Azure Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("RoleRoot") read access denied error

Tags: azure

I have an xml file that I ma tryin to read from

```
string xmlTemplatePath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("RoleRoot") + @"\", @"approot\myxml.xml");
```

Using  `XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(xmlTemplatePath)`, however I get an access denied exception both on the cloud and development environment. Any ideas why a read is denied?

Comment: I have the exact same issue - File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open) throws an access denied exception.  The file is certainly there (File.Exists(filename) returns true).  did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I know, old thread... but the answer could be useful to someone nevertheless.

It appears that an azure worker process runs under a custom user (shows up as a GUID in taskmgr).  This user account appears to be quite restricted and has no read-access to the filesystem (even inside the approot directory).

My solution was to create a startup script for the azure role (see [msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg456327.aspx)) which uses icacls to add permissions to access the files.  In this case, I created a file called startup\Install.cmd in my project, containing the following:

```
@echo off

if "%EMULATED%"=="true" goto :EOF

echo Allowing access to files
cd directory_where_files_exist
icacls *.* /grant Everyone:F
```

In my ServiceDefinition.csdef file, I instruct the Azure deployment system to run this startup script during deployment by putting this inside the role definition (e.g. <WorkerRole>):

```
<Startup>
  <Task executionContext="elevated" commandLine="startup\Install.cmd">
    <Environment>
      <Variable name="EMULATED">
        <RoleInstanceValue xpath="/RoleEnvironment/Deployment/@emulated" />
      </Variable>
    </Environment>
  </Task>
</Startup>
```

The variable "EMULATED" is set when the emulator is running - note that in the startup/Install.cmd file above, I skip doing the permission change if running in the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Looks fine to me. I even grabbed your code and dropped it into a worker role, calling it from OnStart(), after creating myxml.xml in my project root, just to make sure I wasn't missing something obvious.

Check myxml.xml properties: "Build Action" should be "Content" and "Copy to Output Directory" should be "Copy always" or "Copy if newer". If that doesn't fix it, check permissions on that file.